# why can't I have an xs:element using ref as a global element in a XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am experimenting with **ref** attributes in <**xsd:element**> and don't get the following:

while an <**xsd:element**> with a **ref** attribute can be defined in the non-global scope (i.e. not directly below <**schema**>), as in:

### ref1.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://www.dummy-example.com"
xmlns:foo="http://www.dummy-example.com">


<xs:element name="a" type ="xs:string"/>

<xs:element name="b">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="foo:a"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

So that, e.g. the following validates with [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html):

## ref1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo:b xmlns:foo="http://www.dummy-example.com">
    <foo:a>whatever ...</foo:a>
</foo:b>
```

However, I cannot have the referencing element be directly at the global level. E.g. the following:

## ref2.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://www.dummy-example.com"
xmlns:foo="http://www.dummy-example.com">
    <xs:element name="a" type ="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element ref="foo:a"/>
</xs:schema>
```

**does not** validate *ref2.xml* below:

## ref2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo:a xmlns:foo="http://www.dummy-example.com">
    whatever
 </foo:a>
```

In fact **xmlint** complains during the parsing of the **xsd** file, even before reaching the **xml** file:

```
ref2.xsd:6: element element: Schemas parser error : Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element': The attribute 'name' is required but missing.
```

## UPDATE

Following the accepted answer, I found the constraint spelled out in the [XML Schema Primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#ref36):

> One caveat is that global declarations cannot contain references; global declarations must identify simple and complex types directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would you expect a top level `ref` to provide that a top level declaration doesn't already give you?  If

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://www.dummy-example.com"
xmlns:foo="http://www.dummy-example.com">
    <xs:element name="a" type ="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element ref="foo:a"/>
</xs:schema>
```

were allowed, it would just say "a document conforming to this schema can have a top level element named `a` in the `http://www.dummy-example.com` namespace, or alternatively a top level element named `a` in the `http://www.dummy-example.com` namespace" - it would add nothing beyond simply

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://www.dummy-example.com"
xmlns:foo="http://www.dummy-example.com">
    <xs:element name="a" type ="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: makes sense - I 've just failed to locate the prohibition against top-level refs spelled out explicitly.